# click function was executed everytime the document is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>click demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body> 
<script>
    for(var c=1; c<=5; c++){
        var btn = $("<button>Button "+c+"</button>");
        btn.click(new function(){
            alert("You click button "+c);
        });
        $("body").append(btn);
   }
   </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Can someone explain to me why the click function get executed everytime the page is loaded? I am expecting the button to show an alertbox when it is clicked but unfortunately nothing happens! Any idea?

Comment: What you are trying to do ?

Comment: remove the `new ` from callback function

Comment: @Ethyl Please specify what are you trying to achieve. And also do what  Pranav said in the previous comment remove the new in front of the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `new` from the button click handler.
Also, you need to update the code to get correct index of the button clicked as follow. Use wrap the code inside the `for` in *closure*.

```
for (var c = 1; c <= 5; c++) {
    var btn = $("<button>Button " + c + "</button>");
    (function (c) {
        btn.click(function () {
            alert("You click button " + c);
        });
    }(c));
    $("body").append(btn);
}
```

---

**EDIT**

A better way would be to use [`event delegation`](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) with `data-*` attributes to store information in HTML elements.

```
for (var c = 1; c <= 5; c++) {
    var btn = $("<button class='myButton' data-title=" + c + ">Button " + c + "</button>");
    $("body").append(btn);
}

$(document.body).on('click', '.myButton', function() {
    document.write('You clicked ' + $(this).data('title') + ' button');
});
```

Comment: Just a little thought of mine: I agree event delegation can be a good alternative, but it exposes the value in the DOM, making it possible to be modified by ill-intentioned user, where OP's code wouldn't, unless I am mistaken and that the value could still be modified somehow in the OP's code, but I don't think so.

Comment: @cram2208 `event delegation` is the better approach here, since OP is adding new buttons to the `body`, we've to use `document.body` to delegate event. Also, adding event in the loop is bad practice when you can add event on only once

Comment: good point about adding event is a bad practice I got your point, but what about Ill-intentioned person who could modify the value in event delegation form, could their be any even solution to address your point and mine somehow ? I know the OP might want this degree of security, but I wonder for my own purposes, in a context where this point is paramount. What are your thoughts on this, if my point proves relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `new` before the function. Creating a function in such a way invokes it as it takes it as a constructor.

```
for(var c=1; c<=5; c++){
        var btn = $("<button>Button "+c+"</button>");
        btn.click(function(){
            alert("You click button "+c);
        });
        $("body").append(btn);
   }
```

As you can see here:

```
var myFuncValue = new function() {};
```

Returns:

```
{}
```

While

```
var myFuncValue = function() {}
```

Returns

```
[Function]
```

Imagine that you are giving JQuery the `myFuncValue`, it will try to invoke the first value which is an empty object in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your code to:

```
for(var c=1; c<=5; c++){
    var btn = $("<button>Button "+c+"</button>");
    btn.on('click', function(){
        alert("You click button "+c);
    });
    $("body").append(btn);
}
```

You just have a mistake in your event assignment. [Check jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kmsdev/Lj4r22wc/)